# Adding JScrollPane with JTextArea into JDailog

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea, jdialog

```
public class DailogDemo 
{

private JDialog chatdailog;
private JTextArea chatHistory;
private JScrollPane mScrollMessage; 

DailogDemo()
{
chatdailog=new JDialog();
chatdailog.setSize(300, 400);

chatHistory=new JTextArea();
chatHistory.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,100));
mScrollMessage=new JScrollPane();
mScrollMessage.add(chatHistory);
mScrollMessage.setBounds(4, 10, 150, 100);
mScrollMessage.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
chatdailog.add(mScrollMessage);
chatdailog.show();
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    new DailogDemo();
}
}
```

In the above code, I can't able to see the JTextArea in JScrollPane.  Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- use [JTextArea(int rows, int columns)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html)
- don't set and remove `chatdailog.setSize(300, 400);`
- don't set and remove `chatHistory.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,100));`
- don't set and remove `mScrollMessage.add(chatHistory);` use `JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);` instead
- don't set and remove `mScrollMessage.setBounds(4, 10, 150, 100);`
- don't set and remove `chatdailog.show();` use `chatdailog.setVisible(true);`
- add code line `chatdailog.pack()` before line `chatdailog.setVisible(true);`
- if is there another parent for this `JDialog` wrap `chatdailog.setVisible(true);` into `invokeLater()`

Answer (score 1):

If you have a layout, you can use `new JTextArea(24, 32)` and `pack()` to get a nice arrangement.

Answer (score 0):

set size for JTextArea

```
chatHistory.setSize(new Dimension(width,height));
```